# Android app crash by "FileNotFoundException for drawable in drawable-xhdpi-v4"

Tags: android, gradle

guys.I got a crash becasue of "java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/component_tip_loading1.png".
But I unziped my apk and found the resource is existed.
And my build.gradle set minifyEnabled is true, but not set the shrinkResources.
Thanks for any advice.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/component_tip_loading1.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:405)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2443)
```

Comment: Please post your code also where you get issue.

Comment: Hi,this is path.https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201345